# How to start business rule execution using crm 2015 sdk?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way to start business rule execution using crm sdk? It has configured *Entity* scope.

Thanx.

Comment: As mentioned by James Wood, Business Rules are server side (alternative to JavaScript).  Do you have any more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I added more details on answer from James. Thanx for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the business rule is set for server side execution I think you should just have to do something that triggers the business rule. Rather than calling the business rule explicitly.

E.g. if business considers some field in a condition, then change that field.

Comment: Thanx for your answer James. The thing is that business rule has rollup field in conditions. Updating rollup field will not trigger business rule execution, so I'm searching for workaround. I couldn't find any details about this in sdk documentation. The last option for this workaround will be including some dummy condition in BR which will contain other field, and cause BR execution.